# Record team call with a bot using MS-Teams

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

Can we record the team meeting discussions [ audio ] using a bot joined in the meeting? After discussion can we get the recorded session [ audio file ].

Comment: why don't you use the recording button?

Comment: Yeah, we can, but I want to implement as a feature like:  pull the bot into the meeting, record the discussion and extract the audio later for processing.

Comment: I just noticed that you may probably add the bot to the meeting during invitation, if this is the case then the bot has an advantage. It should be possible for the bot to take it's own recording, because there is a permission to access it. `Calls.AccessMedia.All - Access media streams in a call as an app (preview)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot#add-microsoft-graph-permissions

Comment: or ... maybe not : `You cannot use the Microsoft.Graph.Calls.Media API to record or otherwise persist media content from calls or meetings that your bot accesses."`